# jQuery undefined when included at the end of document and used in HTML body

Tags: jquery

I am trying to optimize my wordpress page (with google's paespeedtest). It says, that I should include all my javascript-files bundled, minified and at the bottom of the page.
I've done that with W3C Total Cache. It does it's job.

But my wordpress theme, unfortunately, produces some *jQuery()*-calls inside inline script-tags within the HMTL body. And since jquery is not loaded at that point this leads of course to *jquery is undefined* errors.

- I could include jQuery in my header, but this decreases my ranking.
- I could probably adjust the theme-template (actually it is in a plugin of my bought theme), but I really don't prefer to do this

What other choices do I have here?

Is there some kind of possibility to override the jquery-function until jquery is loaded?

**UPDATE**

The term *ranking* was probably misused. I meant the pagespeed-scoring, which decreases due to:

"Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript in above-the-fold content. 
Your page has 1 blocking script resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
Remove render-blocking JavaScript:
http://../…0/26f57/default.include.fde404.js?87e337"

Comment: This is related to following SO question I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691487/dynamically-loaded-jquery-not-defined-when-using-inline-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [possible solutions(s)](https://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/17/stop-paying-your-jquery-tax) - whether I like it or not.
Funnily it's provided by an stackoverflow developer. It's is also discussed [on hacker news](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3602121).

**Pushing jQuery to the footer**

*Turns out that pushing jQuery to the footer is quite easy for the common case. If all we want is a nice $.ready function that we have accessible everywhere we can explicitly define it without jQuery. Then we can pass the functions we capture to jQuery later on after it loads.
In our header we can include something like:*

```
window.q=[];
window.$=function(f){
  q.push(f);
};
```

*Just after we load jQuery we can pass all the functions we captured to the real ready function.*

```
$.each(q,function(index,f){
  $(f)
});
```

*This gives us access to a "stub" ready function anywhere in our page.*

**UPDATE**

[This blogpost](http://writing.colin-gourlay.com/safely-using-ready-before-including-jquery/) provides a better approach and explains it in more depth.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice imo is to use [Content Delivery Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) and keep jquery in header. There's huge chance that user has jQuery from CDN already cached. That also seems to [works for google's rank](https://www.iispeed.com/blog/cdn-google-page-speed-optimization).

You can use [jQuery on cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/). Its probably most popular.

Comment: I updated my question. The word ranking was misued, I meant the pagespeed-scoring.